# How to create a distorted screen

Tags: iphone

I want to show distorted image as error page for my application. If possible this can be a screenshot of home screen with some graphics distortion. Is this possible.

Thanks You.

Comment: Apple will not allow this. You are prohibited from creating something that makes the "core experience" - other apps, screen, device - appear broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel A. White's comment mentions, this probably will cause your application to be rejected from the App Store, but it can be accomplished in many ways. I think this technique would be acceptable if your own interface appeared broken, but not acceptable if you made any iOS supplied looks appear broken.

You could just use your favorite image editor (i.e. Photoshop) to distort a screen shot, and displayed it by putting it in a separate UIView. The image would be static.  It couldn't react to the contents of your program's interface.

If your interface is drawn with OpenGL ES 2.0, you could draw your regular interface to a texture, then use that texture as input to another GLSL program that applied the distortion.

Comment: the simulation of a nonfunctional device, like a broken screen (glass cracked), or a crash in the graphics core that distorts the screen is never allowed. Doesn't matter if it's you own app.